# How to render a component using variable or props?

Tags: reactjs

The class receives the `props.name` which is the name from another Component, but it not renders properly.

```
class Component extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    var Element = this.props.name;
    return (  
        <Element />
    )
  }
}

const Dropdown = () =>{
    return(
    <div>
       <select>
          <option value="initial" selected>Select...</option>
          <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
          <option value="lime">Lime</option>
          <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    components: []
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Component components={this.state.components} name="Dropdown" />          
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

The component renders fine when I write manually the name of the Component. For example:

```
render(){
  var Element = this.props.name;
  return (  
       <Dropdown />
  )
}
```

Comment: can you show how you are passing from parent component?

Comment: @MayankShukla done

Comment: instead of passing the string, try this: `name={Dropdown}` and use the same code.

Comment: @MayankShukla it was! If you wish post it to vote as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect to generate `Component` out of string???

Do this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    components: []
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Component components={this.state.components} name={Dropdown} />          
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the props as tag argument. ex: . see the below example.

```
class parent extends React.Component{
constructor(){
super();
this.state={
   name:'ABC',
 }
}
render(){
   return(
  <Child argument={this.state.name} />
  )
 }
}

//stateless component don't have state
 function Child(props){
 return <div>{this.props.arguments}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the string from parent component, pass it like this:

```
<Component components={this.state.components} name={Dropdown} />
```

I think reason is:

`<Element>`  will get converted into `React.createElement(Element, {})` and which expect the first argument as a react component name, or a string (HTML tag), since you want to render a react component so don't pass the name as string.

Answer (score 0):

In the `render()` method you have to return one React element. That React element has to be a representation of DOM element. In your case you're trying to render a string, and that's the reason why isn't rendered (as you said) 'properly'. See documentation of `render()` method [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render).

I've updated your code so the `name` component is successfully rendered:

```js
class Component extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    var Element = this.props.name;
    return (
    <div>
      {Element}
    </div>
    )
  }
}

const Dropdown = () =>{
    return(
    <div>
       <select>
          <option value="initial" selected>Select...</option>
          <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
          <option value="lime">Lime</option>
          <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    components: []
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Component 
        components={this.state.components}       
        name={<div>Dropdown</div>}/>          
      </div>
    );
  }
}


React.render(<App/> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```